# RPI official cam results in 256x192 resolution only

Tags: camera, motion

I use motion to get data from my official rpi camera. This camera allows to use more than 256x192 px resoultion.

Problem: Only 256x192 resolution seems possible, even if 1024 resolution is configured.

part of `/etc/motion/motion.conf`

```
# Image width (pixels). Valid range: Camera dependent, default: 320 
width 1024

# Image height (pixels). Valid range: Camera dependent, default: 240 
height 768
```

service starts well!

`less /var/log/motion/motion.log`:

```
[1:ml1] [CRT] [VID] [Nov 09 23:03:52] vid_mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
[1:ml1] [WRN] [VID] [Nov 09 23:03:53] jpgutl_decode_jpeg: JPEG image size 1024x768, JPEG was 256x192
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should post your problem (and logs) as an issue at https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/issues

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/motion/motion.conf you've got width & height settings. On my motion system (with an original 5MP picamera V1) I've set those to:

```
# Image width (pixels). Valid range: Camera dependent, default: 320 
width 1024

# Image height (pixels). Valid range: Camera dependent, default: 240 
height 768
```

Comment: updated my answer to clear things up. the resoultion is already configured...

Answer (score 0):

setting the v4l2_palette to 17 (Y12) results in successful captures with a original NoIR camera.